# Most effective way to fade in/fade out objects in Cycles. Version 3.6

Tags: cycles-render-engine, compositing-nodes, transparency

I have seen a couple of similar posts, but one dated back to 2018 and the next was 2017.

I am on version 3.6 and I was wondering what the most effective way is to fade in and/or fade out an object in cycles, so that there is not a black smokey material left over.  The smokey material appears when trying to use the alpha layer in the BDSF and decreasing the amount.  I read in one of the posts that increasing the transparency in the light paths would help, but they hasn't made an effect on the render.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.  I'm so used to AE and the system's layers, which makes it easy to manipulate the transparency of an object or layer.  I would really appreciate on how to do this the compositor, if it is the most effective way.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean with "black smokey material leftover", would you mind posting a screenshot of how it looks like and how you've set it up? This is how it looks when I animate the _Alpha_ channel in the _Principled BSDF_ shader (sorry for bad GIF quality): [alpha transparency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWBX3.gif)

Comment: If possible please attach an image showing the issue and show how you set up the blending nodes.

Comment: I figured out that the smokey cloud went away if I increased the light paths in transparency.  My apologies for the response.  Been a crazy busy few weeks.  I appreciate you for responding!